# Keeping persistent connections from a home-made Java server

Tags: java, persistent

I've built a simple Java program that works as a server locally.

At the moment it does a few things, such as previews directories, forwards to index.html if directory contains it, sends `Last-Modified` header and responds properly to a client's `If-Modifed-Since` request.

What I need to do now is make my program accept persistent connections. It's threaded at the moment so that each connection has it's own thread. I want to put my entire thread code within a loop that continues until either `Connection: close`, or a specified timeout.

Does anybody have any ideas where to start?

Edit: This is a university project, and has to be done without the use of Frameworks.

I have a main method, which loops indefinitely, each time it loops it creates a Socket object, a `HTTPThread` object is then created (A class of my own creation) - that processes the single request.

I want to allow multiple requests to work within a single connection making use of the `Connection: keep-alive` request header. I expect to use a loop in my `HTTPThread` class, I'm just not sure how to pass multiple requests.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you explain again what do you mean when you say "persisted connections"? Do you probably want to save the session state in order to restore it if session was temporary disconnected?

Comment: My problem is that I don't full understand what I need to do! At the moment I have a loop that calls a class called HTTPThread. It passes an inputStream and an outputStream. The HTTPThread class then parses the request accordingly. If the connection state is keep-alive, i want to use the connection I already have for the next request somehow..

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are implementing the HTTP protocol code yourself starting with the Socket APIs.  And that you are implementing the persistent connections part of the HTTP spec.

You can put the code in the loop as you propose, and use Socket.setSoTimeout to set the timeout on blocking operations, and hence your HTTP timeouts.  You don't need to do anything to reuse the streams for your connection ... apart from not closing them.

---

I would point out that there are much easier ways to implement a web server.  There are many existing Java web server frameworks and application servers, or you could repurpose the Apache HTTP protocol stacks.

Comment: I have a loop currently that declares a socket for every single request. A HTTPThread object (where all my code is), accepts an inputstream and an outputstream and processes the individual request in there. How could I perform multiple requests from inside the HTTPThread class - a single connection?

Comment: what does soTimeout have to do with a persistent connection?

Comment: As outlined here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection, HTTP 1.1 always uses persistent connections unless otherwise indicated in the header. Apache 2.2 closes the socket after idle for 5 seconds. So you have to not close the socket but also set some timer to close it if it has been idle too long. One way to do this would be to have a dedicated management thread that handles this (and maybe other) tasks.

Comment: This is a university project unfortunately - it has to be done in basic simple java - unfortunately nobody knows how to even begin implementing it!

Answer (score 0):

1. If it should act like a web service: Open 2 sockets from the client side, one for requests, one for
   responses. Keep the sockets and streams open.

   You need to define a separator to notify the other side that a
   transfer is over. A special bit string for a binary, a special
   character (usually newline) for a text-based protocol (like XML).
2. If you really try to implement an own http-server, you should rather make use of a [library](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-servers) that already implements the HTTP 1.1 connection-keepalive standard.

Comment: its homework i doubt the right solution is to use a library that already does it.

Comment: I understand, then you should implement it by yourself, of course. ;) The Java Socket API provides a method to set the SO_KEEPALIVE: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive(boolean)

Comment: i think keep alive on a socket is different than HTTP 1.1 persistent connections.

Comment: The http persistent connection is a higher level of abstraction, but if you implement the whole stuff by yourself, you need to make use of these socket methods.

Comment: why is that? socket keep-alive is to notify of dead peers, and keep a connection alive when there's no traffic (via sending zero length packets with ACK). HTTP persistent connections keep a socket open for a short period for performance because each client is likely to make several requests in a short period of time. Besides the names being similar I don't see how they're related.

Comment: Didn't notice that, thank you. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183409/http-1-1-persistent-connections-using-sockets-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to get you started:

This wikipedia article describes HTTP 1.1 persistent connections:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

You want to not close the socket, but after some inactive time period (apache 2.2 uses 5 seconds) you want to close it.

You have two ways to implement:

1. in your thread do not close the socket and do not exit the thread, but instead put a read timeout on the socket (whatever you want to support). When you call read it will block and if the timeout expires then you close the socket, else you read next request. The downside of this is that each persistent connection holds both a thread and a socket for whatever your max wait period is. Meaning that your solution doesn't scale because you're holding threads for too long (but may be fine for the purposes of a school project)!
2. You can get around the limitation of (1) by maintaining a list of tuples {socket,timestamp}, having a background thread monitor and close connections that timeout, and using NIO to detect a new read on an existing open socket. So after you finish reading the initial request you just exit the thread (returning it to the thread pool). Obviously this is much more complicated but it has the benefit of freeing up request threads.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how do you read the next request.. I think that's where I'm really stuck. Also, at no point do I call a method to close the socket, I close the input and output streams, does that do the same thing?

Comment: in which case are you interested in? In the first case you go into read on the input stream and it blocks until the client sends another request, or the timeout happens, or the client forcibly closes the connection. In the second case you do the same thing with non-blocking IO apis, and that means the read returns immediately, but when new data is available on the stream you find out from some select loop which is running in a different thread.

Comment: if you close the socket it will close the input and output streams as well.